# Is this Poisson Distribution Solution Correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Q: you share a picture on Instagram. You know that the average likes you get per hour is 12, and it follows a Poisson distribution.
What's the probability of getting your first like in the first 10 minutes after sharing a new image?**

So, I basically said that you get 0.2 likes per minute on average, and multiplied this by 10 to get 2 - i.e. 2 likes on average per 10 minutes. Then I slotted this into the Poisson formula, using 2 as the mean and x as 1 (i.e. probability of getting one like). The answer I got is 27.07%. Is this the correct answer, or have I made a mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An important issue in applications of the Poisson distribution is to
use a rate $\lambda$ that matches the application at hand. You have hinted at this issue by finding the rate per minute.

Thus in your case
you want the rate of likes per 10 minutes which is $12/6 = 2,$ as you say.
However, for $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 2),$ you seek 
$P(X > 0) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1- e^{-2}.$

You would "get your first like" within 10 minutes, if you got 1, 2, or even 37
likes within 10 minutes.